# C++ range-for and boost::irange

Tags: c++11, boost

I'm using `boost::irange` and created a helper function to simplify the code by removing the need for explicit template parameters. I don't understand why it doesn't work. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/range/irange.hpp>

template<typename T>
boost::irange<T> range_from_zero(T limit)
{
    return boost::irange<T>(T(), limit);
}

int main() {
    size_t end = 100;
    for (auto i  : range_from_zero(0,end))
        std::cout << i << ' ';

    return 0;
}
```

There's a live version here https://ideone.com/VVvW6e, which produces compilation errors

```
prog.cpp:5:8: error: 'irange<T>' in namespace 'boost' does not name a type
 boost::irange<T> range_from_zero(T limit)
        ^
prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:12:41: error: 'range_from_zero' was not declared in this scope
     for (auto i  : range_from_zero(0,end))
```

If I use `boost::irange` directly in the range-for, then it works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/range/irange.hpp>

int main() {
    size_t end = 100;
    for (auto i  : boost::irange<size_t>(0,end))
        std::cout << i << ' ';

    return 0;
}
```

this works fine: https://ideone.com/TOWY6H

I thought maybe is was a problem using range-for on the return of a function, but it isn't; this works using a `std::vector`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/range/irange.hpp>

template<typename T>
std::vector<T> range_from_zero(T limit)
{
    auto range = boost::irange<T>(T(), limit);
    return { std::begin(range), std::end(range) };
}

int main() {
    size_t end = 100;
    for (auto i : range_from_zero(end))
        std::cout << i << ' ';

    return 0;
}
```

See https://ideone.com/TYRXnC

Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 6):

---

But, first off, what's wrong with **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3d1f99e1ac425b05)**

```
for (size_t i : irange(0, 100))
```

or even **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/439c906b0c47925c)**

```
size_t end = 100;
for (auto i : irange(0ul, end))
```

---

`irange` is a function template, and it cannot be used as a return type.

The return type is `integer_range` or `strided_integer_range`. As such, `irange` is already the function you were looking for.

Only, you didn't pass arguments that could be *unambiguously* deduced. If you can to allow this, "copy" `irange()` implementation using separate template argument types for the boundary values and use e.g. `std::common_type<T1,T2>::type` as the range element.

---

Here's my stab at writing `range_from_zero` without naming implementation details in the interface:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6ab767c2b788a95f)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/range/irange.hpp>

template <typename T>
auto izrange(T upper) -> decltype(boost::irange(static_cast<T>(0), upper)) {
    return boost::irange(static_cast<T>(0), upper);
}

int main() {
    size_t end = 100;
    for (size_t i : izrange(end))
        std::cout << i << ' ';
}
```

Comment: Too much typing. If `irange` take 0 and `end` which is `size_t`, then the template parameter has to be specified, or something like `size_t(0)` used instead.

Comment: Woah. I answered the first part of the question while I tested the rest. Changing the function to `boost::integer_range<T> range_from_zero(T limit)` fixed the compilation error. Thanks.

Comment: @cdmh and I realized you may specifically have been looking for the `range_from_zero` function prototype. See update (and **[live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6ab767c2b788a95f)**). Although, of course `range_from_zero` must be `izrange` (because too much typing :))